# Trying to scrape a website with scrapy - Not receiving any data

Tags: scrapy

For an assignment I have to fetch from data from a Kaercher webshop. The data I need to fetch is the product Title, description and price.

Additionally I need to be able to fetch multiple products (high pressure cleaners, vacuum cleaners, ...) with the same script. So I probably need to make a .csv keyword file or something to adjust the URL accordingly.

However, I can't seem to be able to fetch the data with my current script..

Info: I will add my entire file structure and current code. I only adjusted the actual spider file (karcher_crawler.py), the other files are mostly default.

My folder structure:

```
scrapy_karcher/ # Project root directory
    scrapy.cfg  # Contains the configuration information to deploy the spider
    scrapy_karcher/ # Project's python module
        __init__.py
        items.py      # Describes the definition of each item that we’re scraping
        middlewares.py  # Project middlewares
        pipelines.py     # Project pipelines file
        settings.py      # Project settings file
        spiders/         # All the spider code goes into this directory
            __init__.py
            karcher_crawler.py # The spider
```

My "karcher_crawler.py" code

```
import scrapy

class KarcherCrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'karcher_crawler'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.kaercher.com/nl/webshop/hogedrukreinigers-resultaten.html'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        products=response.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-3 col-xs-6 fg-products-item']")
        # iterating over search results
        for product in products:
            # Defining the XPaths
            XPATH_PRODUCT_NAME=".//div[@class='product-info']//h6[contains(@class,'product-label')]//a/text()"
            XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE=".//div[@class='product-info']//div[@class='product-price']//span/text()"
            XPATH_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION=".//div[@class='product-info']//div[@class='product-description']//a/text()"

            raw_product_name=product.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_NAME).extract()
            raw_product_price=product.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE).extract()
            raw_product_description=product.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION).extract()

            # cleaning the data
            product_name=''.join(raw_product_name).strip(
            ) if raw_product_name else None
            product_price=''.join(raw_product_price).strip(
            ) if raw_product_price else None
            product_description=''.join(raw_product_description).strip(
            ) if raw_product_description else None

            yield {
                'product_name': product_name,
                'product_price': product_price,
                'product_description': product_description,
            }
```

My "items.py" code:

```
import scrapy


class ScrapyKarcherItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

My "pipelines.py" code:

```
class ScrapyKarcherPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

my "scrapy.cfg" code:

```
[settings]
default = scrapy_karcher.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = scrapy_karcher
```

Comment: There is no product details in the source HTML code. These values are loaded from this AJAX call `https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/result/20035386?isocode=nl-NL`

Comment: @gangabass thank you very much for your comment. I am relatively new to data science (scraping). Do you know how I deal with this, and how did you find those results?

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to request the required data using the following code:

Spider file (.py)

```
import scrapy
from krc.items import KrcItem
import json

class KRCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "krc_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["kaercher.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = KrcItem()
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for company in data.get('products', []):
            item["productid"] = company["id"]
            item["name"] = company["name"]
            item["description"] = company["description"]
            item["price"] = company["priceFormatted"]
            yield item
```

items file (.py.

```
import scrapy


class KrcItem(scrapy.Item):
    productid=scrapy.Field()
    name=scrapy.Field()
    description=scrapy.Field()
    price=scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Thanks to @gangabass I managed to locate the URL's which contain the data I needed to extract. (you can find them in the "Network" tab when you are inspecting a webpage (press F12 or right click anywhere to inspect).